# Are dynamic stability and model convergence/divergence separate concepts?

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-calculus

As applied to a system of simultaneous differential equations:

For a model to be convergence:
the absolute value of the characteristic roots (for simplicity assuming distinct & real, for an n = 2 system) must be less than 1.
|r|< 1

But I've come accross another rule about stability. For a system of difference equations (same assumptions, n = 2). The model is dynamically stable if both characteristic roots are negative. Excluding exceptions and saddle points etc. are these two concepts mutually exclusive, or do I have something mistaken here?

How can a system be divergent but stable? For instance in this case if r is two negative numbers where their absolute values are still < 1.

Comment: You seem to have things mixed up here. For discrete-time systems, the linear stability criterion is that all $|r|<1$. For continuous-time systems, it's that all $r$ have negative real part. And of course no system is of both types at the same time, so there's no contradiction.

Comment: How would one discriminate between systems using time discretely vs one using it continuously? Is it specified mathematically/explicitly? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Or rather to make the question easier. How does it follow that: "Given a system of linear autonomous differential equations, the intertemporal equilibrium level will be asymptotically stable i.e., y(t) will converge to Y (steady-state) as t --> infinity, IFF all the characteristic roots are negative." Is it just the fact that it's referring to intertemporal equilibrium level that makes it the case? I understand what you said, but now I'm trying to mathamatically see the explicit difference between the time dimension represented discretely vs continuously.

Comment: As soon as you're talking about differential equations, it's a continuous-time system ($t \in \mathbb{R}$). Difference equations have discrete time ($n \in \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: I've never heard the term “intertemporal equilibrium” before, but I assume that it just means an ordinary equilibrium (namely the origin, in case of a linear system). And the statement isn't quite correct, it should be that all characteristic roots have negative **real part**.

Comment: That clears it up. Intertemporal equilibrium seems a side nomenclature concern. My best guess is the text covers systems of equilibrium in economics. Given 'real world' application, these models at their best reach an equilibrium intertemporally before another shift changing the entire dynamics. Not to mention the fact that these models are 'wrong' in that they endogenize variables arbitrarily. Just a guess though -- if not correct I'd be curious what it would characterize instead.